# Fixing historical command-line corruption from PS1 escape sequence

Tags: bash, corruption, ps1

I (believe) I am having an issue with the following PS1 not properly having an escape sequence:

\x1b[35mabc\x1b[0m \x1b[33mxyz\x1b[0m \x1b[34m\w\x1b[0m\$

The prompt looks okay until I begin to use historical command-lines and then bash seems to lose where the start of the line is.  I thought that [this stack overflow question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28827/why-is-my-bash-prompt-getting-bugged-when-i-browse-the-history) would help, but I really don't know where my escape sequence is missing.  Is it that I'm missing closing brackets?  Also, I'm a little confused why I have \x1b instead of \.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the brackets comletely (both opening and closing).  Try using

```
\\[\x1b[35m\\]abc\\[\x1b[0m\\] \\[\x1b[33m\\]xyz\\[\x1b[0m\\] \\[\x1b[34m\\]\w\\[\x1b[0m\\]\$
```

That is, put `\\[` and `\\]` around *every* escape sequence in the prompt.

My personal solution is to use a two-line prompt (so there's a \n in PS1) where the second line is short and has no escapes.  So bash has no trouble figuring out how wide it is:

```
PS1='\033[0;31m[\h${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}] \033[0;32m[\u] \033[0;33m[\w$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\033[0;39m\n --> '
```